# Obtener una imagen de Drawable mediante variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo varias imagenes en drawable y quiero guardar el nombre de la imagen en este caso son pokemon para luego meterlo en un .icon de google maps y mostrarlo.

Es decir yo tengo este código:

```
                ciudad= new LatLng(pokemon.getDouble("latitude"),pokemon.getDouble("longitude"));
                nMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(ciudad)
                        .title(nombre)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.charmander))
                        .snippet(pokemon.getString("pokemon_id")
                        )
                );
```

Entonces he intentado en una variable como esta:

> String imagen = charmander;

Y añadirla a :

> .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.imagen))

o algo como

```
String imagen = R.drawable.charmander;

.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(imagen))
```

Pero no me funciona ningún caso, como podría hacerlo o que manera seria la correcta? Esto lo quiero ya que más adelante voy a hacer un switch y dependiendo del nombre que muestre en la posición un pokemon o otro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes el nombre del recurso puedes usarlo para obtener el valor del recurso

```
String imagen = "charmander";
int drawableResourceId = getResources().getIdentifier(imagen, "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

al obtener el id ahora puedes cargar la imagen:

```
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(drawableResourceId))
```